# SharePoint site Keep Asking for password After IISRESET

Tags: 2013, iis, login, windows-authentication, credentials

Even Many Question Regarding SharePoint Prompting for password again and again but,Even I can't find Exact solution

When IIS reset to cache clear, site working fine ,but after some time same prompting issue occurs

My Configuration:

- Normal CPU USage:30-40%
- RAM usage : 88-90%
- RAM - 12 GB

-->  site added in trusted site

-->  no ULS logs for that particular login fail

--> no Event Error

Comment: Can you check the identity of application pool of your central admin and your custom web app? Change it to a credentials that should not expire. Try to recycle the application pool and perform anotehr iisreset then try to access the site. Also add this account into the user policy of web appln.

Comment: any special rights need to have which user configure for that pool? @SaMolPP

Comment: Are there any requests to a different website? e.g. an IFRAME or you gather data frome elsewhere?

Comment: No , that site not contain any kind of reference,But in that server Using VS working on Web site development, is this affected? @Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw my CPU usage there is lot of memory consume by the search service application, some of below cases are helpful to this situation

- If you have not using search functionality then disable the search service application
- search configure in different server
- Search crawl schedule in off hour from central admin,in this case you can schedule your crawl in night time where CPU is free